# How do you use ToDictionary with IEnumerable<string>> as one of the types?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, ienumerable

When I try to use .ToDictionary() to convert `Dictionary<string, string>` to a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` I get an error

```
public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> ConvertDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
     return data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new List<string> { y.Value });
}
```

The error I get is "Cannot Implicitly Cast `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`

I tried this, but you can't create an instance of an abstract type

```
return data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new IEnumerable<string> { y.Value });
```

I tried this, but .ToDictionary() doesn't let you specify the types this way

```
return data.ToDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(x => x.Key, y => new List<string> { y.Value });
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using IEnumerable<string> over List<string>?

Comment: Existing code, and because it prevents unnecessary casting as a result of linq queries

Answer (score 0):

Use "as" in the Linq statement to convert it

```
public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> ConvertDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
     return data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new List<string> { y.Value } as IEnumerable<string>);
}
```